# Angular pass result of observable through pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to combine few observables and passing the value from first one through the entire pipe.

```
this.auth.user
      .pipe(
        switchMap((authUser) => {
          if (!authUser) {
            return of();
          }

          const docRef = doc(this.firestore, firebaseCollections.UsersCollection, authUser.uid);
          return from(getDoc(docRef));
        }),
        map((user)=>{
          if(user){
            return true;
          }
          return false
        }),
        switchMap([authUser, exists])={
          
        }
      )
```

On the last switchMap I would like to get the `authUser` from the from the first **switchMap ** but also the value from the **map**. I know I've done it in the past put can't find the solution anymore.

I guess it should be something like this but not sure witch rxjs functions should I use:

1: (authUser) => getFirestoreUser(authUser)

2: (authUser, firestoreUser) => {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a expertice in rxjs, but I feel you need "map" your intermediate response. Some like

```
this.auth.user
      .pipe(
        switchMap((authUser) => {
          if (!authUser) {
            return of([null,null] as [any,any]);
          }
          const docRef = doc(this.firestore, firebaseCollections.UsersCollection, authUser.uid);
         //see that you use here pipe(map) to return an array
          return from(getDoc(docRef)).pipe(
              map((x:any)=>[x,authUser] as [any,any])
          );
        }),
        map([user,authUser]:[any,any])=>{
          if(user){
            return [authUser,true] as [any,boolean];
          }
          return [authUser,false] as [any,boolean]
        }),
        switchMap([authUser, exists]:[any,boolean])={
          
        }
      )
```

NOTE: I use the "as [any:any]" to keep the type of the users